# CSS height 100% of its parent

Tags: html, css

i have this page: http://www.nyccriminallawyer.com/felonymisdemeanor/
what i want to do is make the left inner box (the white one with Felony/Misdemeanor as title called .in_left) to be of 100% height of its parent (called .inner)

codes are here:

```
.in_left {
float: left;
width: 721px;
margin-top: 10px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
line-height: 24px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px -4px #000;
}

.inner {
background: #CCD7CC;
margin-top: 1px;
color: #5A5A5A;
padding: 10px;
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

i have tried height: 100% and min-height as well, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Heights in percent only work if the parent element has an explicit height set itself – otherwise the rendering engine might end up with situations where the parent’s height depends on the child’s and vice versa at the same time, and that would be unsolvable.

Comment: Just with CSS this is kind of hard to achieve in your design...

Comment: @CBroe - nice, that's a really intuitive way to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use float on `.in_left` and `.in_right`, use `display:table-cell;` on those and, most importantly, use `display:table;` on their container:

```
.inner {  
    display: table;  
}  
.in_left {
    width: 229px;
    /* other style */
    display: table-cell;  
}  
.in_left {
    width: 721px;
    /* other style */
    display: table-cell;  
}
```

Comment: +1 I was about to answer the same thing, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4n5aG/ -- the browser support is good too, ie8+

Comment: brilliant! I have never heard of this technique before, thank you for the new information :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend a child to be 100% the height of its parent, but you can make it look like it extends using the [Faux Columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) technique.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the height of an element 100% only works if the parent elements height is somehow fixed (like height: 300px). But you can set the child element absolutely positioned (to its immediate parent) and set it's position in four directions:

```
.in_left {
  ...
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/OkIQUCi/1/

Comment: Your answer states "set the child element absolutely positioned" but the code says `position: relative;` ? In any case I don't think you would get this working properly with dynamic content. Care to share a demo?

Comment: Sorry for typo. Demo attached.